# How does ssh always manage to reset the terminal attributes?

Tags: terminal, system-calls, strace

If I run

```
strace -e trace=ioctl -v ssh some_remote_host
```

I see a line like this:

```
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {c_iflags=0x6006, c_oflags=0x4, c_cflags=0x
4bf, c_lflags=0xa00, c_line=0, c_cc[VMIN]=1, c_cc[VTIME]=0, c_cc="\x03\x1c\x7f\x
15\x04\x00\x01\xff\x11\x13\x1a\xff\x12\x0f\x17\x16\xff\x00\x00"}) = 0
```

Which makes sense: `ssh` has to change a lot of terminal settings, for example:

- it turns off `ISIG` because ^C and ^Z should interrupt and suspend the process on the remote host, not the `ssh` process running locally;
- it turns off `ICANON` because it wants to receive keyboard input unbuffered rather than line buffered;
- it turns off `ECHO` because whether echoing occurs should depend on the attributes set on the remote host's pseudo-terminal, instead of occurring automatically on the local terminal

If you now exit the `ssh` session, the original terminal attributes are restored by a second `ioctl` call:

```
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {c_iflags=0x6d02, c_oflags=0x5, c_cflags=0x
4bf, c_lflags=0x8a3b, c_line=0, c_cc="\x03\x1c\x7f\x15\x04\x00\x01\xff\x11\x13\x
1a\xff\x12\x0f\x17\x16\xff\x00\x00"}) = 0
```

But what I find strange is that even if `ssh` is killed with `SIGKILL` before it has the chance to make the second `ioctl` call, you get the original terminal attributes back. Otherwise you would notice that something is very wrong (for example commands typed into the shell would *not* be echoed). How does `ssh` manage to ensure that the original terminal attributes are restored even if it's not around to call `ioctl` again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell knows that `ssh` died and can reset the terminal.

Tracing a bash shell while I kill a child `ssh` shows that it makes several ioctl() calls.

```
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
ioctl(255, TIOCSPGRP, [52631])          = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=25, ws_col=147, ws_xpixel=902, ws_ypixel=329}) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCSWINSZ, {ws_row=25, ws_col=147, ws_xpixel=902, ws_ypixel=329}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {c_iflags=0x500, c_oflags=0x5, c_cflags=0xbf, c_lflags=0x8a3b, c_line=0, c_cc="\x03\x1c\x7f\x15\x04\x00\x01\x00\x11\x13\x1a\x00\x12\x0f\x17\x16\x00\x00\x00"}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {c_iflags=0x400, c_oflags=0x5, c_cflags=0xbf, c_lflags=0x8a31, c_line=0, c_cc[VMIN]=1, c_cc[VTIME]=0, c_cc="\x03\x1c\x7f\x15\x04\x00\x01\x00\x11\x13\x1a\x00\x12\x0f\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00"}) = 0
```